# Springboot AuthInfoInterceptor Inject a FeignClient will report a error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

Springboot AuthInfoInterceptor Inject a FeignClient will report a error.
Now I have a modul A with a FeignClient AService.
Second,I have a modulB B depend on A.
Third，B have a Interceptor called `public class AuthInfoInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor`
If I user Autowired inject AService like this:

```
@Component
public class AuthInfoInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Autowired
    private AService aService;
}
```

it will report a error：
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcResourceUrlProvider': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:355) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]

I know i can user `@Lazy`,but i want to know why will report this error